# Unable to Create List of Object from Json String

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, lombok, jsonparser

```
@Data
@Builder
public class A implements Serializable {
    private List<B> bList;
}
@Data
@Builder
public class B implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String lname;
}
```

In My main class i am trying to create List from json String. Using **`objectMapper.readValue()`**

it's working fine as long as i will not kept @Builder annotation on Class A and B.

But when i am trying to create List using same String with @Builder annotations it's started throwing error

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of A**

 (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Comment: Please add test as well as controller code instead of only a description.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am not able to get List of object from json string while using `@Buiilder` annotation. As my main object contains another object inside of it.

Comment: Again please add the code instead of only a desciption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your code as below

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class A implements Serializable {
    private List<B> bList;
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String lname;
}
```

Comment: `@Dara containse` `@NoArgConstructor `inside of it.